# (a+b)^n manual function

Tags: homework

My first post here, I'm quite new in *Mathematica*, and I can't see why I'm not getting anything printed or returned. I guess the definition of `suma` is  wrong? I know there is a already ready function like `Expand` but this is homework. entry for this function should be `n`, the greater exponent we want.

Thanks in advance, here is my code:

```
aplusbn[n_] :=
 Module[{suma, a, b, k},     
   suma[a_, b_] := Sum[(n!/(k!*(n - k)!))*a^(n - k)*b^k, {k, 1, n}]
   Print[suma]
   Return[suma];]
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is also useful for learning how to format your questions and answers. You may also find [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: What are `a` and `b`? There's no need for `Print[]` or `Return[]`. Try something like this: `aplusbn[n_] := 
 Module[{suma, a, b, k}, 
  suma[a_, b_] := Sum[(n!/(k!*(n - k)!))*a^(n - k)*b^k, {k, 1, n}]; 
  suma[1, 2]]`, then call `aplusbn[5]`

Comment: How about something like this? Allows you to plug all the parameters into the function
`aplusbn[n_, a_, b_] := Module[{suma},
  suma = Sum[(n!/(k!*(n - k)!))*a^(n - k)*b^k, {k, 1, n}] ]` you could then call this with your values for n,a,b, using  `aplusbn[n, a, b]`

Comment: The formatting of your edit confuses me a little about what your actual code is.  Two things seem likely problems: There's no `;` separating `Sum[]`, `Print[]` from `Return[]` from each other, so they're being multiplied; further, they all become part of the definition of the ***function*** `suma`.  Returning `suma` won't return the sum because it does not evaluate to anything without two arguments; perhaps you want `suma = Sum[...]`.

Comment: But a and b, should be variables, not numbers. Symbolic

Comment: @Dede Why not `aplusbn[n_, a_, b_] := Sum[(n!/(k!*(n - k)!))*a^(n - k)*b^k, {k, 1, n}]`?

Comment: I want to see this output for aplusbn[3]=  a^3+3a^2b+3ab^2+b^3

Comment: fsimja, if @Dede's edit reflected your intent, I've formatted it so that the code is indented properly.  If it does not, there is a rollback button after you the "edit..ago" link in the middle between your post and my user icon.  You can use it to go back your previous edit.

Comment: `aplusbn[n_] := 
 Module[{suma, k}, Sum[(n!/(k!*(n - k)!))*a^(n - k)*b^k, {k, 1, n}]]`

Comment: @fsimja How about `aplusbn[n_] := Expand[(a+b)^n];`?  Or `aplusbn[n_Integer?NonNegative] := Expand[(a+b)^n];`, if you want to restrict `n`?

Comment: @MichaelE2 certainly the way to go here, I just went with his choice for module in case he wanted to add more calculations to it. Another reason is that he states he doesn't want to use `Expand`.

Comment: @Dede This site is interesting. I've seen such a question with many simple syntax errors be treated like lions attacking an antelope. But this time, the OP gets half a dozen helpful suggestions. Glad to see so many people in a good mood. :)

Comment: @MichaelE2 I'm fairly new to Mathematica myself so I do my best to help those I can help.

Comment: @fsimja `aplusbn[n_] := 
 Sum[(n!/(k!*(n - k)!))*a^(n - k)*b^k, {k, 1, n}]; aplusbn[n]` Like this? (replace n with your desired number)

Comment: @dede thanks. :)

Comment: @MichaelE2 how to put this question closed (answered)?

Comment: You could post an answer to your own question, with the solution you like.  If it's from someone's comment, you should give them credit in your answer.  If you don't, it might be closed (now called "put on hold") by a community voting process. I suspect that might happen eventually.  The weekends can be slow times on the site.

Answer (score 1):

```
aplusbn[n_] := Sum[(n!/(k!*(n - k)!))*a^(n - k)*b^k, {k, 1, n}]; aplusbn[n]
```

Credits for @Dede